# Large space at break in tcolorbox

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox, vertical-spacing, white-space

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=3in, multi={my}, crop, ignorerest=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia, lipsum, forloop}
\usepackage[most, magazine]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  breakable,
  break at=3 in,
  enhanced,
  height fixed for=all,
  compress page=all,
  pad at break*=0mm,
  enlargepage flexible=2\baselineskip,
  boxrule=2mm,
  bottomrule=16mm,
  overlay app={%
    \node[white, font=\footnotesize, anchor=south, text width=.95\textwidth, text centered, minimum height=16mm] at (frame.south) {Footer1 \\ Footer2};},
  title=#2,#1}

\newcommand{\xxbody}{%
  \lipsum[1-2]%
}

\newcommand{\xxheading}{%
  Heading
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[reset box array, store to box array]{\LARGE \xxheading{}}

  \xxbody{}

\end{mybox}%


\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 10}%
{%
\begin{my}
  \useboxarray{\thect}
\end{my}
}

\end{document}
```

With `pad at break*=0mm` I was expecting tightly fitting text in the broken boxes. But there is a huge space at the bottom of each broken box.

What is happening? How do I set this right?

Answer (score 4):

You have a bottom rule set to 16mm. Just add `bottomrule at break=2mm` *after* it (not before, otherwise, `bottomrule` overwrites `bottomrule at break`).

```
\documentclass[varwidth=3in, multi={my}, crop, ignorerest=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia, lipsum, forloop}
\usepackage[most, magazine]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  breakable,
  break at=3 in,
  enhanced,
  height fixed for=all,
  compress page=all,
  pad at break*=0mm,
  enlargepage flexible=2\baselineskip,
  boxrule=2mm,
  bottomrule=16mm,
  bottomrule at break=2mm,
  overlay app={%
    \node[white, font=\footnotesize, anchor=south, text width=.95\textwidth, text centered, minimum height=16mm] at (frame.south) {Footer1 \\ Footer2};},
  title=#2,#1}

\newcommand{\xxbody}{%
  \lipsum[1-2]%
}

\newcommand{\xxheading}{%
  Heading
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[reset box array, store to box array]{\LARGE \xxheading{}}

  \xxbody{}

\end{mybox}%


\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 10}%
{%
\begin{my}
  \useboxarray{\thect}
\end{my}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]